# How to remove back button from navigation bar in whole app using swiftui iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing an application UI with **Swift UI**, and I would like to remove `Back button` from `Navigationbar` from whole app. is there any way to remove `Back Button`.

Comment: Downvoted because you event looked for the first basic SwiftUI tutorial from Apple

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine and correct, for example you get the step by step implemntation from [SwiftUI Developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/working-with-ui-controls)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Target Color Block")
            Text("Target Color Block")
             Button(action: { 
                 /* handle button action here */ })
            {
         Text("your Button Name")
          .color(.white)
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
     }


        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: if you want to perform in label see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with some SwiftUI tutorials.

SwiftUI is a complete change from UIKit and so buttons no longer have target/actions.

To add a button you can use...

```
Button(action: { /* Do something here */ }) {
    Text("Press me")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly written in the documentation of SwiftUI of how to use it. Also suggest you to watch the [Introducing SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/204) talk from this year WWDC.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.action() }) {
            Text("Button Text")
        }
    }

    private func action() {
        print("Do magic")
    }
}
```