# SwiftUI - Two buttons in a List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've got two buttons in a list, tho when tapping, the full area of the list item is highlighted. Is there a way to separate the two buttons?

In this case I've got an Action button and an Info button:

[image]

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row), tho no direct solution.

Here's the code:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(control.name)
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            print("action")
        }) {
            Text("Action")
            }
            .frame(width: 250 - 10)
            .padding(5)
            .background(Color(white: 0.9))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .frame(width: 250)
        Group {
            Button(action: {
                print("action")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that yet - as a temporary workaround, you could replace the list with a `ForEach` of `HStack`, where `HStack` will be your row content. Be aware that the styling won't be the same - `List` is more refined in that sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI - Multiple Buttons in a List row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row)

Comment: @Fogmeister That solution uses .tapAction, a working solution, tho the highlight states are lost..

Comment: @Fogmeister I combined it with one button and one tapAction of the info image, it's a working solution for now.

Comment: try .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Set the button style to something different from the default, e.g., BorderlessButtonStyle()

```
struct Test: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach([
          "Line 1",
          "Line 2",
        ], id: \.self) {
          item in
          HStack {
            Text("\(item)")
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { print("\(item) 1")}) {
              Text("Button 1")
            }
            Button(action: { print("\(item) 2")}) {
              Text("Button 2")
            }
          }
        }
        .onDelete { _ in }
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
      }
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
    .accentColor(.red)
  }
}
```

Comment: `.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())` did it! thanks!

Comment: Also worked for me. Who would've thought a 'styling' modifier would solve an interaction issue! Love SwiftUI but this certainly feels unintuitive.

Comment: You are a savior really hard to figure out, I think SwiftUI need to evolve a lot

Comment: You are the man for this, could not figure it out. thank you!

Answer (score 13):

I struggled with this issue for a while. Apple has made `Button` kind of special in SwiftUI. It can change depending on the context it's used. That is why we see this weird functionality when a `Button` is inside a `List`.

Fortunately, there are other ways using `.onTapGesture`. Try out the code below.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(control.name)
        Spacer()
        Text("Action")
            .frame(width: 250 - 10)
            .padding(5)
            .background(Color(white: 0.9))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .frame(width: 250)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("action1")
            }
    
        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("action2")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works! Tho not sure how to highlight the button, on down and up events, any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: In the latest version of SwiftUI `tapAction` became `onTapGesture`

Answer (score 4):

On Xcode 12.5 I've had the same issue in SwiftUI, the full area of the list item being highlighted when tapped.

**.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())** does the job, and now the two custom button can be tapped separately on the list item.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having a similar problem with the latest SwiftUI (Xcode 11.2) and multiple `Button`s in a `HStack`, I got my problem solved only after converting *all* buttons in the `HStack` to `Image`s and adding the `.onTapGesture` handler.

The problem in my case was that tapping on one button triggered all other buttons in the `HStack`. Only after I converted all buttons to images did they stop interfering with each other.

Of course, if your buttons don't have an image, you can use `Text` instead.

Comment: Had an issue with buttons in a list row as well where tapping anywhere in the list would trigger one of the button actions, but adding a `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` to each button helped restrict the tap zone to the actual buttons themselves.

Comment: Had the same problem in an HStack. Text works but of course you don't get the default styling. Weird bug... assume this will be fixed in next version of Xcode. thx

Answer (score -7):

You can add `padding` or try adding `Spacer`

**Add Padding**

```
HStack {
        Text("Button")
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            print("action")
        }) {
            Text("Action")
            }
            .frame(width: 250 - 10)
            .padding(5)
            .background(Color(white: 0.9))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .frame(width: 250)
        Group {
            Button(action: {
                print("action")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
            .padding(15)
        }
    }
```

**Add Spacer**

```
HStack {
        Text("Button")
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            print("action")
        }) {
            Text("Action")
            }
            .frame(width: 250 - 10)
            .padding(5)
            .background(Color(white: 0.9))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .frame(width: 250)
        Spacer()
        Group {
            Button(action: {
                print("action")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried your code?, Will this solve the real problem?