# SwitUI - Two navigationLink in a list

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, vstack

I have two NavigationLink in a cell of my List

I want to go to destination1 when I tap once,and go to destination2 when I tap twice.
So I added two tap gesture to control the navigation.

But when I tap,there are two questions:

- 1 The tap gesture block won't be called.
- 2 The two navigation link will be both activated automatically even if they are behind a TextView.
  The real effect is: Tap the cell  -> go to Destination1-> back to home -> go to Destination2 -> back to home

Here is my code :

```
struct MultiNavLink: View {
    @State var mb_isActive1 = false;
    @State var mb_isActive2 = false;
    
    var body: some View {
        return
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ZStack {
                        NavigationLink("", destination: Text("Destination1"), isActive: $mb_isActive1)
                        NavigationLink("", destination: Text("Destination2"), isActive: $mb_isActive2)
                        Text("Single tap::go to destination1\nDouble tap,go to destination2")
                    }
                    .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {()->Void in
                        NSLog("Double tap::to destination2")
                        self.mb_isActive2 = true
                    }).onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {()->Void in
                        NSLog("Single tap::to destination1")
                        self.mb_isActive1 = true
                    })
                }.navigationBarTitle("MultiNavLink",displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried remove the List element,then everything goes as I expected.
It seems to be the List element that makes everything strange.

I found this question:[SwiftUI - Two buttons in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56576298/swiftui-two-buttons-in-a-list),but the situation is different from me.

I am expecting for your answer,thank you very much...

Comment: I think your architecture is incorrect. Try removing the `ZStack` and `NavigationLink` from the `List` and replace with a `Button`, then apply the `.onTapGesture` modifiers to the `Button`, embedding the NavLinks in the `perform` code for each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following approach - the idea is to hide links in background of visible content and make them inactive for UI, but activated programmatically.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
struct MultiNavLink: View {

    var body: some View {
        return
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    OneRowView()
                }.navigationBarTitle("MultiNavLink", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct OneRowView: View {
    @State var mb_isActive1 = false
    @State var mb_isActive2 = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Single tap::go to destination1\nDouble tap,go to destination2")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .background(Group {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination1"), isActive: $mb_isActive1) {
                    EmptyView() }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination2"), isActive: $mb_isActive2) {
                    EmptyView() }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }.disabled(true))
        .highPriorityGesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
            self.mb_isActive2 = true
        })
        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
            self.mb_isActive1 = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution perfectly meets my needs.

At last,I find that when a list cell contains multi navigation links,you tap the cell once,all the navigation links will be activated.

A key point is set them `disable(true)`,and active every single navigation link by other separately logic.

Comment: @Asperi I'm convinced you are a genius

Answer (score 0):

Navigation link has a initializer that takes a binding `selection` and whenever that `selection` is set to the value of the NavigationLink `tag`, the navigation link will trigger.
As a tip, if the app can't differentiate and identify your taps, and even with two taps, still the action for one-tap will be triggered, then you can use a simultaneous gesture(`.simultaneousGesture()`) modifier instead of a normal gesture(`.gesture()`) modifier.

```
struct someViewName: View {
    
    @State var navigationLinkTriggererForTheFirstOne: Bool? = nil
    @State var navigationLinkTriggererForTheSecondOne: Bool? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: SomeDestinationView(),
                           tag: true,
                           selection: $navigationLinkTriggererForTheFirstOne) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: AnotherDestinationView(),
                           tag: true,
                           selection: $navigationLinkTriggererForTheSecondOne) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            
            NavigationView {
                    Button("tap once to trigger the first navigation link.\ntap twice to trigger the second navigation link.") {
                        // tap once
                        self.navigationLinkTriggererForTheFirstOne = true
                    }
                    .simultaneousGesture(
                        TapGesture(count: 2)
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                self.navigationLinkTriggererForTheSecondOne = true
                            }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This element works well  when I  use it without list element.

But when I put the element in a list, tapped it, and it also does not act as we expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scalable solution I implemented after having the same issue of multiple `NavigationLinks` not working in the SwiftUI `List` and this solution also (optionally) removes the disclosure indicator that appears in the cells with `NavigationLinks`. For me, I had a large list with many possible view scenarios and special parameters needing to be passed to the new navigation view depending on which button and cell index it was clicked from. I also didn't want to make a State variable for each individual cell to maintain memory performance.

```
@State var navigationParameter: (Int, String?) = (0, String?) // can be really anything that's needed for the navigation context.
@State var navigationIsActive: Bool = false

var body: some View {
   ZStack {
       List(0..<12) { i in
           HStack {
               Button(action: {
                   navigationParameter = (i, "firstBtn")
                   navigationIsActive.toggle() // ensure this comes after setting the parameter context
               }) {
                    Text("button")
               }.buttonStyle(.borderless) // sometimes needed if one button consumes entire cell tap

               // Second button
               Button(action: {
                   navigationParameter = (i, "secondBtn")
                   navigationIsActive.toggle()
               }) {
                    Text("button")
               }.buttonStyle(.borderless)
           }
        }

        NavigationLink(destination: navigationView(), isActive: $navigationIsActive) { }     
     }
}

    @ViewBuilder
    func navigationView() -> some View {
        if navigationParameter.1 == "secondBtn" {
            YourSecondButtonView(i: navigationParameter.0)
        } else {
            YourFirstButtonView(i: navigationParameter.0)
        }
    }
```

Basically it uses an empty `NavigationLink` placed in the List's parent view where parameters can be forwarded to the `navigationParameter` state variable to dictate the `NavigationLinks` destination view whenever the `navigationIsActive` variable is toggled. I think this is a greatly scalable solution for those who want the benefits of the SwiftUI List but can't seem to format and get it to function properly.