# Multiple NavigationLink inside a List using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to have two `NavigationLink`s inside a struct that I use as a `NavigationLink`  inside a `List` with `ForEach` but the code does not work (the navigation does not happen to either `View`) , here is the code:

```
struct mainView : View {
    @State var people = [Person(name: "one", family: "1", type: "men"),Person(name: "two", family: "2", type: "women")]
    var body : some View {
        List{
           ForEach(self.people, id:\.self){person in 
               NavigationLink(destination: Text("hi")) {
                 PersonView(person : person)
               }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}


struct Person {
    var name : String
    var family : String
    var type : String
}

struct PersonView : View {
    @State var person : Person?
    var body : some View {
      HStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.person.name)) {
           Text("this is \(self.person.name) \(self.person.family)")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.person.type)) {
           Text(self.person.type)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I have added the `.buttonStyle`  after reading it might help but it did nothing. I also tried the following PersonView :

```
struct PersonView : View {
@State var person : Person?
@State var goToFirst = false
@State var goToType = false
var body : some View {
   VStack{
      Button(action:{
         self.goToFirst.toggle()
      }){
         Text("this is \(self.person.name) \(self.person.family)")
      }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
      Button(action:{
         self.goToType.toggle()
      }){
         Text(self.person.type)
      }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
      NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.person.name), isActive : self.$goToFirst) {
           Text("").frame(width: 0.01, height: 0.01)
      }
      NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.person.type), isActive : self.$goToType) {
           Text("").frame(width: 0.01, height: 0.01)
      }
   }
}
```

This did not work as well, what am I supposed to do so when I click anywhere on the cell it will navigate to `Text("hi")`  and when I click on the respective areas it will navigate to the proper `View` .
**Important:** This view is getting navigated to from a view that is wrapped with a `NavigationView`

Comment: Consider this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497247/switui-two-navigationlink-in-a-list. Your case should be solved with same approach.

Comment: The thing is that I want it to be two separate "buttons" that the user can click and not to double tap on the cell like in the case of what you sent

Answer (score 0):

You have not added a navigationView, that is the problem.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var peoples = [Person(name: "one", family: "1", type: "men"),Person(name: "two", family: "2", type: "women")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { //This is important
            List {
                ForEach(self.peoples, id: \.name) { people in
                    NavigationLink(destination: PersonView(person: people)) {
                        Text(people.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Demo")
        }
    }
}

struct Person {
    var name : String
    var family : String
    var type : String
}

struct PersonView : View {
    @State var person : Person?
    var body : some View {
      HStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.person.name)) {
           Text("this is \(self.person.name) \(self.person.family)")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.person.type)) {
           Text(self.person.type)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This view is navigated to from a different view that is wrapped in a navigationView

Comment: @TheMachineX best to post a concise but complete example of your problem, because now this person has put effort in an answer that's not usable right now

Comment: 100% , forgot to add that

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want. The code can be pasted into an empty project.

Some clarifications:

The `List` seems to make things more difficult, so I replaced it with a `VStack`. You may need to surround it with a `ScrollView`.

Also, like user Asperi hinted, this works best when you create multiple `NavigationLink` but around an `EmptyView` that is then later activated.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var people = [Person(name: "one", family: "1", type: "men"), Person(name: "two", family: "2", type: "women")]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.people, id: \.self) { person in
                PersonView(person: person)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Person: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var family: String
    var type: String
}

struct PersonView: View {
    let person: Person
    @State private var selection: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: Text(self.person.name),
                tag: self.person.hashValue + 1,
                selection: self.$selection) {

                EmptyView()
            }
            NavigationLink(
                destination: Text(self.person.type),
                tag: self.person.hashValue + 2,
                selection: self.$selection) {
                
                EmptyView()
            }
            
            Button("this is \(self.person.name) \(self.person.family)") {
                self.selection = self.person.hashValue + 1
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(self.person.type) {
                self.selection = self.person.hashValue + 2
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question was specific to a List, this answer simply removes the List.