# Swiftui Navigationlink in foreach Crashes when two items in list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-foreach

I have this view with a foreach where I want go go into the details view when I click an item

```
ForEach(dreams, id: \.id) { dream in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TopDreams(dreams: dream)) {
                        DreamOverviewRow(dreamlist: dream)
                    }
                }
```

This works fine when there is one item in the fetchRequest (dreams) but when I have two items or more all of them "light" up when I click on one of them and I get the following error message

Fatal error: UIKitNavigationBridge: multiple active destinations: file SwiftUI, line 0
2020-09-10 08:56:21.311643+0200 GoalsDream[97124:12329297] Fatal error: UIKitNavigationBridge: multiple active destinations: file SwiftUI, line 0

the code as "a whole" is:

```
NavigationView {
   VStack {
       List {
          ForEach (this one works)
          ForEach (this one does not)
```

Comment: Does your ID variable have the same content for all of them?

Comment: Does this answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63497954/12299030?

Comment: @NotAPhoenix not sure I understand your question, but ID is an UUID and is ofc unique