# How to Programmatically Navigate List by Row Content?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `List` within a `NavigationView` where each view under `List` should have navigatable elements attached to it (cover image, user avatar + name, etc.) For example, clicking the cover image navigates to view A, while clicking the user's name/avatar navigates to view B. Sadly, in all cases, the entire list element was clickable and did not grant the intended behavior.

At first, I tried wrapping my content within a `NavigationLink`.

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Media"), tag: .media, selection: $selection) {
    WebImage(url: URL(string: activity.media?.coverImage?.extraLarge ?? ""))
        .resizable()
        .placeholder { color }
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .frame(width: 90, height: 135)
}
```

This causes an arrow to appear to indicate the view is navigatable for the user but is unwanted in this situation. It was also taking up a lot of space from the view unnecessarily.

My next attempt was to wrap the view and `NavigationLink` in a `ZStack`.

```swift
ZStack {
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Media"), tag: .media, selection: $selection) {
        EmptyView()
    }.hidden()

    WebImage(url: URL(string: activity.media?.coverImage?.extraLarge ?? ""))
        .resizable()
        .placeholder { color }
        .cornerRadius(8)
}.frame(width: 90, height: 135)
```

The `.hidden()` modifier was applied to the `NavigationLink` to prevent the arrow from appearing when the image was transparent. While this solution both hides the arrow and cleans up the extra space, there are two issues:

1. The entire list element is still clickable.
2. A `ZStack` covered by the `.frame` modifier requires I know how large I want to make it. The user's name & avatar view can't easily overcome this dilemma.

Thirdly, I tried wrapping the view in a `Button` where the label was the cover image and the action was to change `selection` to navigate programmatically, but this brought the spacing issue from #1 and the overall issue of the list element being clickable.

I later discovered a solution that would cut down the previous issues I had, but brought one problem. To understand it, this is what my main activity view looks like:

```swift
NavigationView {
    List(viewModel.activities) { activity in
        ActivitySelectionView(activity: activity, selection: $selection)
    }.navigationTitle("Activity Feed")
}.onAppear {
    viewModel.fetchActivities()
}
```

By encapsulating `List(...) {...}` in a `ScrollView` and changing `List` to a `ForEach`, I was able to produce the output I wanted: clickable view within an element, the cover image became lighter when clicking on it, opposed to the list element becoming darker as a whole until let go, etc.

However, this is not a list. It does not look good, nor will it look better on other platforms (this is an iOS project). For example, this code does not respect the edges as a list does. It also does not include a divider, but the `Divider` struct can help. I feel this is not the right solution to this problem.

To sum it all up, how do I create a `List` inside a `NavigationView` where the list respects what views inside an element are navigatable?

Comment: you have to use ScrollView for this purpose, you cannot use mo than one navigationLink inside a single cell in a List( you may use , but it does not give expected result  /navigation)

Comment: could you provide the cell view/ a element of the List

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63497954/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi, while that solution does work, it's not the behavior I'm looking for sadly. The list's row content is all clickable, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found an elegant solution to my problem, so I'd like to share it for people who may stumble upon this question in the future.

You need to use a `ScrollView` within the `List {...}` somewhere. In the `ScrollView` block, it's perfectly suitable to make certain elements in the list cell navigatable.

```swift
NavigationView {
  List(1..<11) { num in
    ScrollView {
      Text("\(num)!")

      NavigationLink(destination: Text("Number: \(num)")) {
        Text("Click me")
      }
    }
  }
}
```