# Click listener in custom view triggers all views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I click on a single `Chip` in my view, it triggers the actions in all chips.  For Example, if I click on the "Date" chip, I expect `self.viewModel.showDateSelection.toggle()` to be executed. It does get executed but so does `self.viewModel.showTypeSelection.toggle()` and `self.viewModel.showPointsSelection.toggle()`. I cannot figure out why clicking on one chip would trigger the actions on all chips.

Screen

```
struct EventsScreen: View {

    @EnvironmentObject
    var viewModel: EventsViewModel

    //...

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            List {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    // ...
                    VStack {
                        // ...
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Chip(text: "Dates", action:  {
                                self.viewModel.showDateSelection.toggle()
                            })
                            Chip(text:"Type", action: {
                                self.viewModel.showTypeSelection.toggle()
                            })
                            Chip(text: "Points", action: {
                                self.viewModel.showPointsSelection.toggle()
                            })
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Chip

```
struct Chip: View {
    var text: String
    var action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: self.action) {
        HStack {
            Text(text).foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Image("drop_down").foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 4, leading: 16, bottom: 4, trailing: 16))
        .background(Color.black)
    .cornerRadius(40)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it still issues in SwiftUI to have multiple Button in a List Item

you can use Text with onTapGesture rather than Button to workaround that

refer to this [SwiftUI - Multiple Buttons in a List row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row)