# How to apply a context menu to buttons in a SwiftUI list row?

Tags: swift, swiftui-list, swiftui

When I'm long-pressing on a button in list row, all of context menus for all buttons are shown. It looks like the whole list row is selected. How can I make it so that the context menu is shown only for the pressed button?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row) which is somewhat related, and tried `BorderlessButtonStyle()`. It enables the indiviual buttons in the row to be clickable, but it doesn't solve the context menu problem. I've also tried using `.onTapGesture()` instead of `Button()`, but that didn't work either.

In the example below I'm expecting to see only *Action for button 1* when long-pressing on Button 1 - but *Action for button 2* is also shown.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach((1..<3), content: { _ in
                ListButton()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ListButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()

            Button("Button 1") { }
                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Text("Action for button 1")
                })

            Spacer()

            Button("Button 2") { }
                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Text("Action for button 2")
                })

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ScrollView instead of a List to limit Context Menu to parts of a row.

Comment: @Arman It fixes this specific issue but instead results in losing all the list functionality, like swipe to delete and reordering (which I also need).

Comment: @BenjaminAngeria Any updates on this?

Comment: @George_E Unfortunately not...

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Menu` instead of `ContextMenu` and use the label of the menu to display your button; as alternative solution.

However, to give the buttons gesture more priority than the row itself, you can add `.highPriorityGesture(TapGesture())` to the end of you buttons.

You can achieve what you want by using `Menu` instead of ContextMenu like this:

```
struct ListButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()

            Button("Button 1") { }
                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Text("Action for button 1")
                })

            Spacer()
            // Here I used menu instead of the button 2
            Menu {
                Text("Action for button 2")
            } label: {
                Button("Button 2") { }
                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())

            }.highPriorityGesture(TapGesture())

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just switch to `ScrollView` that fixes your problem!

Comment: That was suggested if you look at the comments on the question. However, that means you lose default list functionality like "swipe to delete" and reordering. I did end up with that approach in the end nonetheless...

Comment: If you ask me it's a bug and for sure Apple won't fix it! switch to scroll view and use custom swipe action.