# SwiftUI - Buttons not working with BorderlessButtonStyle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am attempting to create a list row that contains among other things, multiple individually usable buttons.  Previously, I was able to accomplish this by overlaying the buttons on top of the HStacks in the list, but recently this has ceased to function properly.

From searching around, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row) where the accepted answer suggests using the BorderlessButtonStyle on all buttons to allow them to be individually clicked.  However, whenever I apply this property to my button, as in the following code, the button no longer is able to be clicked at all.

Is this an issue with how I am implementing the BorderlessButtonStyle or a bug in SwiftUI?

```
List{
    HStack {
        Text("Display Name").bold()
        Divider()
        if !self.editing_name{
            Text(Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName ?? "Unknown Name")
        }
        else{
            TextField("Name", text: self.$new_name)
        }
        Spacer()

        Button(action: {
            print("Edit")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

I am currently using Xcode 11.5 / iOS 13.5

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11. 4 / iOS 13.4

Comment: I am currently using Xcode 11.5 / iOS 13.5

Comment: Tested this in 11.5/ iOS 13.5 and it works for me!

Comment: Works for me as well (Xcode 11.5 / iOS 13.5).