# Multiple ContextMenu in swiftUI Form/List row

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is possible to put two objects with two different `contextMenu` in the same row of a `Form`/`List`?

Example:

```
List {
  HStack {
    Image("image.A").contextMenu{ Text("I'm A") }
    Image("image.B").contextMenu{ Text("I'm B") }
  }
}
```

Similar problem of: [SwiftUI - Multiple Buttons in a List row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible approach. Use a `@State` to differentiate between the cases and modify it with a `onLongPressGesture`

Tested on iOS 13.5

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var whichImage: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
          HStack {
            Image("image1").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40).onLongPressGesture {
                self.whichImage = 1
            }
            Image("image2").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40).onLongPressGesture {
                self.whichImage = 2
            }
            
          }.contextMenu{ Text(String(self.whichImage)) }
        }
    }
}
```

Outcome:

[image]