# SwiftUI - Alert doesn't dismiss. It keeps coming back

Tags: swiftui

```
.alert(isPresented:$showingAlert) {
        Alert(
            title: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this?"),
            message: Text("There is no undo"),
            primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                //(using showingAlert = false doesn't help.)
                //(leaving this section empty doesn't help as well so any code written here is unrelated.)
                unrelatedCode()
            },
            secondaryButton: .cancel()
        )
    }
```

Why does this code result in alert coming back to screen no matter which button I press on it?
Here's a vid for easier understanding:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSe9r.jpg

Edit: Seems like a bug on swiftui's side I guess. Guess I'll work around it.

Edit 2: Everything that could be related to the issue:

```
struct EditProcessView: View {
@State var problem:Bool = false
@State var showingAlert = false

@State var text = ""
var body: some View {
    Form{
        //2 unrelated pickers.
        
        //Unrelated textfield
        Button(“Delete”){
            showingAlert = true //Are you sure you want to delete this? Button.
        }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 200, idealWidth: 200)
    .alert(isPresented: $problem) {Alert.init(title: Text(“Fill the textfield with a number.“))}
    .alert(isPresented:$showingAlert) {
        Alert(
            title: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this?"),
            message: Text("There is no undo."),
            primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                //Unrelated code.
               
            },
            secondaryButton: .cancel()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with the view hierarchy. Try moving the .alert() somewhere else in the View?

Comment: check ur unrelatedCode() method  first wether its change the showingAlert.

Comment: @Yodagama Removing the unrelatedCode() and using it as an functionless alert box also causes this so it can't be unrelatedCode()

Comment: @nicksarno Doesn't change anything. Still the same.

Comment: @Shazniq you'll need to add the rest of the code to get an answer

Comment: @nicksarno Done.

Comment: @Shazniq (1) when I run this code and toggle $showingAlert, it only appears once. (2) You can't have two .alerts() in the same view. Instead use one alert and make the title/message dynamic.

Comment: All buttons firing? Likely need PlainButtonStyle, common issue [Bordless or Plain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row)

Comment: If I drop your code into a new ContentView this works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Fatemeh's answer solved the issue, I faced the same issue in iOS 15. And in iOS 16, I can use .toogle() in the button to dismiss the alert with no issue.

```
.alert(Text("Instruction"), isPresented: $showHelp, actions: {
  Button {
   showHelp.toggle() //need to remove this in iOS 15, but no need to remove in iOS 16
  } label: {
    Text("OK")
  }
}, message: {
  Text("some text")
})
```