# Button action in list is executed even when taped outside (but inside the row)

Tags: swiftui, beta, ios15

I have a button in a view that is used for entries in a list.
Currently, the action of the button is executed no matter where you tap within the row.

The following sample code illustrates this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - Model

struct Item {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var subItems: [Item]
    
    var isFolder: Bool { subItems.count > 0 }
}

extension Item: Identifiable { }

class Model: ObservableObject {
    var items: [Item]
    
    internal init(items: [Item]) { self.items = items }
}

extension Model {
    static let exmaple = Model(items: [
        Item(id: 1, name: "Folder 1", subItems: [
            Item(id: 11, name: "Item 1.1", subItems: []),
            Item(id: 12, name: "Item 1.2", subItems: [])
        ]),
        Item(id: 2, name: "Folder 2", subItems: [
            Item(id: 21, name: "Item 2.1", subItems: []),
            Item(id: 22, name: "Item 2.2", subItems: []),
            Item(id: 23, name: "Item 2.3", subItems: [])
        ]),
        Item(id: 3, name: "Item 1", subItems: []),
        Item(id: 4, name: "Item 2", subItems: [])
    ])
}


// MARK: - View

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section("Main…") {
                    NavigationLink {
                        ItemListView(items: Model.exmaple.items)
                    } label: {
                        Label("List", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Label("Select a menu item", image: "menucard")
        }
    }
}

struct ItemListView: View {
    var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            if item.isFolder {
                NavigationLink {
                    ItemListView(items: item.subItems)
                } label: {
                    ItemListCell(item: item)
                }
            } else {
                ItemListCell(item: item)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("List")
    }
}

struct ItemListCell: View {
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: item.isFolder ? "folder" : "doc")
            Text(String(item.name))
            Spacer()
            if !item.isFolder {
                Button {
                    print("button 1 item: \(item.name)")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                }
                Button {
                    print("button 2 item: \(item.name)")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - App

@main
struct SwiftUI_TestApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the `ItemListCell` struct is important. It contains two buttons. If I now tap *somewhere* in the row, the code for both buttons is executed.
Is this the way it should be?
I would like to achieve that tapping the buttons executes the corresponding code and when tapping the row somewhere else, a third action should be executed.

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row

Comment: It solved my issue! Thank you for finding that.

Comment: @D.Mika what was the solution?

Comment: @AbdulRehman: Adding `.buttonStyle(.borderless)`