# How to handle animations of multiple Buttons on List row in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I have a strange animation behavior when using multiple `Button`s inside `HStack` inside `List`. First of all, [I found information that I need to use some button style other than `.automatic` for both buttons to work properly in a single row.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59402642/2402265) That seemed to work great, until I wanted to add animation to those buttons. I Want to create two buttons on each side of the row, but second one is shown only if condition is met, which can be achieved by clicking the first one. Simple example explaining that looks like that:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State
    private var flag1 = true
    @State
    private var flag2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            flag1.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: flag1 ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                    }
                    Text("Some text")
                    if flag1 {
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            withAnimation {
                                flag2.toggle()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: flag2 ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code as above results in this strangely behaving animations:

[image: Bad animation example]

When I remove button style modifier (`.buttonStyle(.borderless)`) animations are better, yet still not ideal. There is animation for transition of second button when it's supposed to hide, but it appears some times with animation and other times without it. Above all, it this situation both button actions are triggered simultaneously:

[image: Good animation example]

The best solution I found is to replace buttons with `.onTapGesture` modifiers:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State
    private var flag1 = true
    @State
    private var flag2 = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: flag1 ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                flag1.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    Text("Some text")
                    if flag1 {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: flag2 ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    flag2.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yet using those I loose on buttons formatting and animation of second button appearing is still working on random. So, here are my questions:

- Is there a way to have 2 `Button`s on one `List` row that doesn't have problems with animations?
- Why appearing transition animation for second button works on random (in cases when I use `.buttonStyle(.borderless)` or using `.onTapGesture`?
- Do I loose much using `.onTapGesture` instead of `Button` and how can I format component in a way it looks like (and stay that way) *normal* `Button`?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to inconsistencies in animation behavior, consider explicitly specifying the transition for the second button's appearance?

In regards to button and onTap... onTapGesture is more flexible but you will have to manage animations and state changes manually.

Just to be clear.. when you click into the "Some text" circle you want the second button to appear visible and with the checkmark indicator?

I achieved the above description by using a Timer to control the appearance of a checkmark inside the second button after a delay, allowing for more control over the animation. I tested the solution below on an actual device (not the simulator), and it seems to be working as expected.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var flag1 = true
    @State private var flag2 = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: flag1 ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                flag1.toggle()
                                
                                // Toggle flg2 after 5 second delay
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        flag2 = true // Set flg 2 to true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    Text("Some text")
                    if flag1 {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: flag2 ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Adding explicit `transitions` helped a bit, but in real application, when it depends on Core Data objects rather than simple `@State` variable I still get situations when sometimes transition animations don't work for some reason. Also I discovered why those buttons animations looks, so weird when `.borderless` style is applied - it's a press effect that in other styles applies to whole row thus animation looks much better.
Your code doesn't represent what I'm trying to achieve. Both buttons should control state only of they own, not one button for both flags.

Comment: Glad the transitions helped a bit. Ah I see, my mistake. The code you first posted did work for me without strange behaviour. I think you are right Core Data can sometimes introduce complexities. Updating Core Data on a background thread can cause strange behavior, especially when dealing with SwiftUI animations. Are Core Data updates and subsequent animations being performed on the main thread??....example: onChange(of: coreDataObject) { newValue in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Update view here based on Core Data changes
    }
}