# Unexpected behaviour of button actions inside of a SwiftUI List

Tags: list, button, swiftui

I'm facing a peculiar situation that has caused me to lose hours of work, and I'm eager to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

Here is my simplified view:

```
struct ToggleTextButton: View {
   var titles: [String]
   
   var body: some View {
     HStack {
       ForEach(titles, id: \.self) { title in
                      Button(action: {
                          didSelect(title)
                      }) {
                          Text(title)
                              .padding()
                              .background(.blue)
                              .foregroundColor(.white)
                              .clipShape(Capsule())
                      }
                  }
     }
   }

   func didSelect(_ title: String) {
     print("Will select:", title)
   }
 }
```

And here's a simple example:

```
List {
  ToggleTextButton(titles: ["A", "B", "C"])
  // other ToggleTextButton...
}
```

When pressing the button titled "A",  I would expect the output to be:

`Will select: A`

However, here's the actual output:

```
Will select: A
Will select: B
Will select: C
```

This issue occurs only inside a List. That means if I use a ScrollView and a VStack, everything works as expected.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Multiple Buttons in a List row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row)

Comment: you prob crashed it with `id: \.self` instead of proper id

Comment: Unrelated but nothing says that array of strings only contains unique values and then the id \.self won’t be unique. Change the type to Set or add an init that takes a Set and then convert it would be a way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of SwiftUI (or maybe a feature :) ). As long as your Button style is being set to `.automatic` which it is by default, you will see this behavior.
As soon as you add `.buttonStyle(.borderless)` or any other Button style, you will see the expected behavior.
For reference see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561064/swiftui-multiple-buttons-in-a-list-row).

Comment: Indeed, this issue is related to the buttonStyle. I must admit that my brain did not anticipate such a cause for this problem, and unfortunately, I overlooked those types of answers on the internet. As I was eagerly seeking a clear explanation for this issue, here's the best answer I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56693263/6712228