# Implementing Flexible Layout for Hashtags in SwiftUI without Explicit Width Calculation

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement a flexible layout for hashtags in SwiftUI, where the hashtags fill up lines and can have multiple lines, similar to the flexbox behavior in CSS. However, I want to achieve this without explicitly calculating the width of each hashtag.

Here's the setup:

I have an array of hashtags, and I want to display them in a view where they are arranged horizontally in rows. When the width of the hashtags exceeds the available width, a new row should be started automatically.

I've explored solutions using HStack, VStack, and ForEach views, but most examples I found require explicitly calculating the width of each hashtag to determine when to start a new row.

Here's a simplified version of what I have:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let hashtags = ["#swift", "#swiftui", "#ios", "#coding", "#programming", "#development", "#mobile", "#app", "#developer", "#tech", "#xcode", "#apple", "#ui", "#ux"]
    
    @State private var arrangedHashtags: [[String]] = [[]]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(0..<arrangedHashtags.count, id: \.self) { index in
                HStack(spacing: 8) {
                    ForEach(arrangedHashtags[index], id: \.self) { hashtag in
                        Text(hashtag)
                            .padding(.vertical, 4)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            calculateArrangedHashtags()
        }
    }
    
    func calculateArrangedHashtags() {
        // Need a solution without explicit width calculation
    }
}

extension String {
    // Function to calculate width
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this:

[image: selected and available tags views]

There's no built-in SwiftUI container to flow your views as you want. But you can write a `Layout` that does it. (You could also use a third-party Swift package like [SwiftUI-Flow](https://github.com/tevelee/SwiftUI-Flow).)

WWDC 2022 had a session about writing custom `Layout`s: [Compose custom layouts with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10056/).

Here's the `Layout` implementation I used to create the animation:

```
struct FlowLayout: Layout {
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let subSizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(proposal) }

        let proposedWidth = proposal.width ?? .infinity
        var maxRowWidth = CGFloat.zero
        var rowCount = CGFloat.zero
        var x = CGFloat.zero
        for subSize in subSizes {
            // This prevents empty rows if any subviews are wider than proposedWidth.
            let lineBreakAllowed = x > 0

            if lineBreakAllowed, x + subSize.width > proposedWidth {
                rowCount += 1
                x = 0
            }

            x += subSize.width
            maxRowWidth = max(maxRowWidth, x)
        }

        if x > 0 {
            rowCount += 1
        }

        let rowHeight = subSizes.lazy.map { $0.height }.max() ?? 0
        return CGSize(
            width: proposal.width ?? maxRowWidth,
            height: rowCount * rowHeight
        )
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let subSizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(proposal) }
        let rowHeight = subSizes.lazy.map { $0.height }.max() ?? 0
        let proposedWidth = proposal.width ?? .infinity

        var p = CGPoint.zero
        for (subview, subSize) in zip(subviews, subSizes) {
            // This prevents empty rows if any subviews are wider than proposedWidth.
            let lineBreakAllowed = p.x > 0

            if lineBreakAllowed, p.x + subSize.width > proposedWidth {
                p.x = 0
                p.y += rowHeight
            }

            subview.place(
                at: CGPoint(
                    x: bounds.origin.x + p.x,
                    y: bounds.origin.y + p.y + 0.5 * (rowHeight - subSize.height)
                ),
                proposal: proposal
            )

            p.x += subSize.width
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the other views I used, along with `FlowLayout`, to create the animation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let tags = [
        "#swift", "#swiftui", "#ios", "#coding", "#programming",
        "#development", "#mobile", "#app", "#developer",
        "#tech", "#xcode", "#apple", "#ui", "#ux"
    ].sorted()

    @State private var selectedTags: Set<String> = []

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section("Selected Tags") {
                FlowLayout {
                    ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                        if selectedTags.contains(tag) {
                            TagView(tag: tag, isSelected: isSelectedBinding(for: tag))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Section("Available Tags") {
                FlowLayout {
                    ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                        if !selectedTags.contains(tag) {
                            TagView(tag: tag, isSelected: isSelectedBinding(for: tag))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
        // The following allows multiple buttons in a list row to work.
        // https://stackoverflow.com/q/56561064/77567
        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
    }

    private func isSelectedBinding(for tag: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
        return .init(
            get: { selectedTags.contains(tag) },
            set: {
                if $0 { selectedTags.insert(tag) }
                else { selectedTags.remove(tag) }
            }
        )
    }
}

struct TagView: View {
    let tag: String
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation {
                isSelected.toggle()
            }
        } label: {
            Text(tag)
                .fixedSize()
                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }
        .padding(2)
    }
}
```